# Is a hand pass cancelled if it touches the other team?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

Is a hand pass washed out if it's deflected by a player of the opposing team?

It happened here: [2/2/18 - Capitals @ Penguins - Period 2 - 8:06](https://youtu.be/KQSLMWdkh3g?t=5m16s).

Answer (score 1):

No. See Rule 79.1 of the [2017-2018 NHL Rulebook](http://www.nhl.com/nhl/en/v3/ext/rules/2017-2018-NHL-rulebook.pdf):

> 79.1 **Hand Pass** - A player shall be permitted to stop or “bat” a puck in the air with his open hand, or push it along the ice with his hand, and the play shall not be stopped unless, in the opinion of the on-ice officials, he has directed the puck to a teammate, or has allowed his team to gain an advantage, and subsequently possession and control of the puck is obtained by a player of the offending team, either directly or *deflected off any player* or official.

(Emphasis mine.)